Which symmetry groups can be made using a given number of vertices
I've been working on a problem that involves optimizing the positions of points on a sphere (what I'm optimizing for is not relevant) and one of the principle challenges is finding starting positions for the minimization function, for which I have decided to leverage symmetry groups. To that end I have begun trying to determine, for each symmetry group, which values of $n$ (the number of points) you can construct that group. For example, for the chiral tetrahedral group $T$, you could construct a shape with that symmetry that has 12 points, or 16 points or any subsequent higher even number. Meanwhile, for the full tetrahedral group $T_d$ you could have 4 or 10 or 12 or most other even numbers (though not 14 or 26).
I could continue on my own, but this feels like a problem that would have been solved already, but I don't know where to look for the solution.
I should also add that it matters to me to some extent how the points are distributed. For instance, with the pyritohedral symmetry group $T_h$, you could make a shape with 24 vertices by placing 1 point inside the fundamental domain, or you could place 2 points on its boundary, on the mirror line. The two shapes below are exemplary of this:



I realize my images aren't especially clear. I thought when I entered descriptions in the editor that they would show up as captions. Both are pyritohedrally symmetric, but for the first, none of its vertices lie on its mirror planes, meanwhile for the latter all of its vertices lie on one of its mirror planes. My point is that this seems  a meaningful distinction that ought to come up in a list of what values of n can be used to construct a shape with this (or any other) symmetry

One place to look would be Cayley's Theorem: every group $G$ embeds in some $S_{X_G}$ for some set $X_G$.  Then look at the subgroups of $S_{X_G}$ with $|X_G|=n$ that are minimal to your requirements.
